# Three questions about homotopy groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This question is a follow up of [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3429408/272127).

> **Q1:** By having a list of homotopy groups and given dimension $n$, Is it possible to recover the topology?

According to [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group): Topological spaces that are *not homeomorphic* can have the same homotopy groups.

> **Q2:** Can anyone give an example of the above fact for smooth manifolds such that they have same dimension?
>
> **Q3:** Can the homotopy groups determine the Euler characteristic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**A1:** No

**A2:** An example can be: $M_1= S^{1} \times (-1,1)$ (i.e Cylinder) and $M_2$ will be the open mobius strip. 
One way to represent the Möbius strip as a subset of three-dimensional Euclidean space is using the parametrization:

$$x(u,v)= \left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos \frac{u}{2}\right)\cos u$$

$$y(u,v)= \left(1+\frac{v}{2} \cos\frac{u}{2}\right)\sin u$$

$$z(u,v)= \frac{v}{2}\sin \frac{u}{2}$$

where $0 \le u< 2\pi$ and $-1 < v< 1$.

They are both Homotopy equivalent to $S^{1}$ so they have the same homotopy groups ([Moebius band not homeomorphic to Cylinder.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1149288/moebius-band-not-homeomorphic-to-cylinder)).

**A3:** They don't as there are spaces with the same homotopy groups but different homology groups([Spaces with equal homotopy groups but different homology groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99302/spaces-with-equal-homotopy-groups-but-different-homology-groups)).